# Generalize method with nullable arguments and return type

Tags: kotlin

I have a method that converts `ByteArray?` to base64 `String?` so that if argument was `null` output will be `null` as well. This is its implementation:

```
fun toBase64String(array: ByteArray?): String? = if(array == null) null else 
    Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(array)
```

But when I pass in not nullable `ByteArray` method returns `String?` which is expected. Is there a way to make it generic so such use case will be possible:

```
val base64 = toBase64String(ByteArray(4))
```

where `base64` will be of type `String` and not `String?` since argument was not nullable?

I just started to work with Kotlin and probably don't know language feature that can make this possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make two overloads, one for nullable `ByteArray?` and one for non-null `ByteArray`:

```
fun toBase64String(array: ByteArray): String =   
    Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(array)

@JvmName("toBase64StringNullable")
fun toBase64String(array: ByteArray?): String? = 
    if (array == null) null else toBase64String(array)
```

<sup>We need `@JvmName("...")` to avoid the declaration clash in the bytecode.
 Also, this allows to distinguish the functions in Java.</sup>

Usage:

```
val nonNullBytes: ByteArray = TODO()
val nonNullString = toBase64String(nonNullBytes) // the inferred type is String

val nullableBytes: ByteArray? = TODO()
val nullableString = toBase64String(nullableBytes) // the inferred type is String?
```

When the argument is of the non-null type `ByteArray`, the compiler will choose the overload that returns a non-null `String`.

Comment: oh, I tried to add overloaded method, but did not do it due to declaration clash. Thank you for pointing on `@JvmName` annotation!

Answer (score 2):

Probably overloading methods is the best solution for your case, but for the sake of completeness here are two other ways to realise that using only one method (the nullable one):

Not-Null-Asserted operator:

```
val base64: String = toBase64String(ByteArray(4))!!
```

Evlis operator:

```
val base64: String = toBase64String(ByteArray(4)) ?: "defaultString"
```

Answer (score 2):

> if argument was null output will be null as well

If that is the only thing the function does when it encounters null argument, it's better to declare it accepting non-null values and use safe call to deal with nulls:

```
fun toBase64String(array: ByteArray): String =   
    Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(array)

val bytes: ByteArray? = ...
val base64 = bytes?.let { toBase64String(it) }
// the same can be written with function reference instead of lambda
val base64 = bytes?.let(::toBase64String)
```

Here `let` function is called only when `bytes` is not null, otherwise the result of the expression is `null`. When called it invokes the lambda function or the function reference specified as its argument, passing `ByteArray` which is already checked to be non-null to that function.

Also it can be more convenient to declare `toBase64String` as an extension for `ByteArray`, so it can be invoked with safe call without the helper function `let`"

```
fun ByteArray.toBase64String(): String =   
    Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(this)

val bytes: ByteArray? = ...
val base64 = bytes?.toBase64String()
```